# How to reset the function command in velato

Tags: velato

I need to be able to stop control A while doing B

I tried reseting factory 6.2 with no luck

Comment: You've tagged your question [tag:dse] but it doesn't seem to be related. What's "velato"? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the console and type `reset`.

Comment: closing the question now!